# using variable outsite while loop not working

Tags: php, variables, while-loop

```
<?php
$sqlsess = "SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE user_name='$session_name'";
$resultsess = mysqli_query($con, $sqlsess);
$usoneid = "";
while ($rowsess = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    global $usoneid;
    $usoneid = $rowsess['User_Id'];
}
var_dump($usoneid);
echo $usoneid;
?>
```

How can I use the `$usoneid` variable outside the `while` loop? The code above echos `oneproduct.php:132:string '' (length=0)` but I want to echo the value of the variable not null.

Comment: Aren't you getting any errors? It seems like you've not defined `$con` which should cause an error -- among some other points of improvement in your code. This could end up in no results.

Comment: No $con previously defined, the result echos oneproduct.php:132: string '' (length=0) but I want to echo the value of the variable not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming you've already assigned `$con` to the result of `mysqli_connect()`. It seems you've misinterpreted the output of `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, a rookie mistake. This is how I usually do something like this. Make sure you always perform [`mysqli_free_result()`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_free_result.asp), if you're saving a MySQLi result type, and then [`mysqli_close()`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_close.asp) your connection.

```
<?php
$sqlsess = "SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE user_name='$session_name'";
$resultsess = mysqli_query($con,$sqlsess);
$usoneid = "";
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
$usoneid = $rows[0]["User_Id"];
echo $usoneid;

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Maybe making clear his problem lays within referencing to the wrong array index would help more. The 2 extra function calls, confused me at first. Also these are not mandatory, yet good practice to use. The result and connection are destroyed anyway when execution finishes.